# how to make ui-view to load a page on startup angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When I run my application it directs to localhost:8080/#/ and the header and footer which I setup in the app.html is called:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <main id="main" class="container-fluid clear-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          //content here
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view id='content-container'></div>
  </main>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  //content here
</footer>
```

I have created two HTML pages and I want one of the html page to be shown when the app first loads.

Code in A.html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="searchAll">
<a class="clear" data-ng-click="clearSearch()">X</a>
```

Code in B.html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="search">
```

I have the following code in my router.js:

```
export default ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      url: '/',
      template: require('./app.html'),
      controller: 'AppCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'app'
    })

    .state('app.A', {
      url: 'A',
      template: require('./A/index.html'),
      controller: 'ACtrl',
      controllerAs: 'a'
    })



    .state('app.B', {
      url: B
      template: require('./B/index.html'),
      controller: 'B',
      controllerAs: 'B'
    });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}];
```

The header and footer should be in all the pages and the page A.html should be loaded when the app starts. Could anyone let me know how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should set your 'app' state as abstracted.

using :

```
//...
abstract:true
//...
```

and removing the url property.

This way, the next app child state with root url "/" will be the first displayed on the screen :

```
.state('app.a', {
      url: '/',
      template: require('./A/index.html'),
      controller: 'ACtrl',
      controllerAs: 'a'
    })
```

Comment: It did not work the page does not load now. Do you want me to get rid of everything defined in the state "app" and just add abstract: true. I have the header and footer in the app.html page.

Comment: Keep your app state as is. Add abstract true to it and remove url. Then put the root url '/' on the app.a state

Comment: Yeah that worked. But when I type in /b in the url it is redirecting it to the main page again instead of calling the b.html page

Comment: Remove the / before B :) in url:'/b'

Comment: In my original code I just added '/' before the url for each state. Like for 'app.B' I made the URL as '/b' and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I think better you call A.html URL in otherwise and keep the header and footer in the index.html instead of creating a separate state for this.

```js
export default ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app.A', {
      url: '/A',
      template: require('./A/index.html'),
      controller: 'ACtrl',
      controllerAs: 'a'
    })



    .state('app.B', {
      url: '/B',
      template: require('./B/index.html'),
      controller: 'B',
      controllerAs: 'B'
    });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/A');
}];
```